# Resin + Oracle + [Spring] + XA Transaction REQUIRES_NEW – Inner Transaction Commit Fails

Tags: oracle, datasource, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions, resin

Could you please help to solve the problem with XA transactions on Resin + Oracle:

We have WebApp which has to execute business transactions which involve both Oracle 11.2.0.1 and Ehcache 2.7. (Actually various combinations possible – two different Oracle data sources (different schemas) with/without Ehcache, etc). This was the reason to switch from plain JDBC usage to JTA transactions demarcation.

We use:
- Resin JTA implementation which is decorated with Spring 3.2.1 to simplify transactions suspending and make use of programmatic approach to transaction boundaries definition (“manual” usage of TransactionManager for suspending/resuming also gives a problem) as follows:

```
public void doOuterTransaction() throws Throwable {
    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName("myTx");
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES);
    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    Connection connection = null;
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = ...; // get cache from CacheManager
        connection = myDataSource.getConnection(); // or "DataSourceUtils.getConnection(myDataSource)" to guarantee same dbConnection from Spring
        // some business logic
        doInnerTransaction();
        // some business logic
        txManager.commit(status);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        txManager.rollback(status);
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (connection!=null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}

public void doInnerTransaction() throws Throwable {
    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName("myTx");
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    Connection connection = null;
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        cache = ...; // get cache from CacheManager
        connection = myDataSource.getConnection(); // or "DataSourceUtils.getConnection(myDataSource)" to guarantee same dbConnection from Spring
        // some business logic
        txManager.commit(status);
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        txManager.rollback(status);
        throw ex;
    } finally {
        if (connection!=null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
}
```

- Ehcache with caches configured with “XA” transactions support.
- Resin connections pool with Oracle driver “oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource”, configured via resin.conf as follows

  ```
  <database>
  <name>my_xa_datasource</name>
  <jndi-name>jdbc/my_xa</jndi-name>
  <driver>
      <type>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</type>
      <url>${MY_DB_URL}</url>
      <user>${MY_DB_USERNAME}</user>
      <password>${MY_DB_PASSWORD}</password>
  </driver>
  <max-connections>50</max-connections>
  <max-idle-time>60s</max-idle-time>
  <max-active-time>24h</max-active-time>
  <max-overflow-connections>15</max-overflow-connections>
  <ping>true</ping>
  <ping-table>DUAL</ping-table>
  <ping-interval>240s</ping-interval>
  <transaction-timeout>24h</transaction-timeout>
  <xa>true</xa>
  </database>
  ```

All transactions with any combination of affected resources with propagation level REQUIRED works fine out of the box. But when we have the case with outer transaction “REQUIRED” and inner transaction “REQUIRES_NEW” – suspending outer transaction causes problems and inner transaction couldn't be committed. And even more - already running inner transaction we can see UNcommited changes from outer transaction which looks completely wrong.

Behavior depends on which resources are involved in outer and inner transactions. We have following cases:
1. Having only Ehcache access in both inner and outer transactions works fine even with REQUIRES_NEW for inner one.

1. Having Ehcache access in outer transaction and DB access ONLY in inner transaction also works fine even with REQUIRES_NEW for inner one.
2. Case with DB access in outer transaction or in both transactions (NO matter how many DataSources are involved, even if DataSources usage does not overlaps transaction boundaries) gives the following error with commit of inner transaction:

_

```
ch.sc.common.ShortAGRuntimeException: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException:
JTA failure on commit; nested exception is com.caucho.transaction.SystemExceptionWrapper:
XA_RMERR: Resource manager error.
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTestServlet.doGet(MyTestServlet.java:34)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:97)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at com.caucho.server.security.SecurityFilterChain.doFilter(SecurityFilterChain.java:132)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppListenerFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppListenerFilterChain.java:114)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1309)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1265)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1249)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1157)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:956)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException:
JTA failure on commit; nested exception is com.caucho.transaction.SystemExceptionWrapper:
XA_RMERR: Resource manager error.
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1025)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.test3(MyTxTest.java:155)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doMainComplexTx(MyTxTest.java:81)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doTxTest(MyTxTest.java:50)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest__ResinScopeProxy.doTxTest(Unknown Source)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTestServlet.doGet(MyTestServlet.java:32)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:97)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at com.caucho.server.security.SecurityFilterChain.doFilter(SecurityFilterChain.java:132)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppListenerFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppListenerFilterChain.java:114)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1309)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1265)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1249)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1157)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:956)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
Caused by: com.caucho.transaction.SystemExceptionWrapper: XA_RMERR: Resource
manager error.
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionImpl.heuristicException(TransactionImpl.java:1040)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionImpl.commitResources(TransactionImpl.java:931)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:886)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:324)
at com.caucho.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:363)
at com.caucho.transaction.UserTransactionProxy.commit(UserTransactionProxy.java:171)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.test3(MyTxTest.java:155)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doMainComplexTx(MyTxTest.java:81)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doTxTest(MyTxTest.java:50)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest__ResinScopeProxy.doTxTest(Unknown Source)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTestServlet.doGet(MyTestServlet.java:32)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:97)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at com.caucho.server.security.SecurityFilterChain.doFilter(SecurityFilterChain.java:132)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppListenerFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppListenerFilterChain.java:114)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1309)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1265)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1249)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1157)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:956)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
Caused by: oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAException
at oracle.jdbc.xa.OracleXAResource.checkError(OracleXAResource.java:1110)
at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXAResource.end(OracleXAResource.java:436)
at com.caucho.sql.DisjointXAResource.end(DisjointXAResource.java:105)
at com.caucho.env.dbpool.ManagedPoolItem.endResource(ManagedPoolItem.java:1017)
at com.caucho.env.dbpool.ManagedPoolItem.commit(ManagedPoolItem.java:957)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionImpl.commitResources(TransactionImpl.java:924)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:886)
at com.caucho.transaction.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:324)
at com.caucho.transaction.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:363)
at com.caucho.transaction.UserTransactionProxy.commit(UserTransactionProxy.java:171)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.test3(MyTxTest.java:155)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doMainComplexTx(MyTxTest.java:81)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest.doTxTest(MyTxTest.java:50)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTxTest__ResinScopeProxy.doTxTest(Unknown Source)
at ch.sc.glibs.mytest.MyTestServlet.doGet(MyTestServlet.java:32)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:120)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:97)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletFilterChain.doFilter(ServletFilterChain.java:109)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at ch.sc.common.http.filters.RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.doFilter(RegexpFilteringProxyFilter.java:65)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.FilterFilterChain.doFilter(FilterFilterChain.java:89)
at com.caucho.server.security.SecurityFilterChain.doFilter(SecurityFilterChain.java:132)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppListenerFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppListenerFilterChain.java:114)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:156)
at com.caucho.server.webapp.AccessLogFilterChain.doFilter(AccessLogFilterChain.java:95)
at com.caucho.server.dispatch.ServletInvocation.service(ServletInvocation.java:289)
at com.caucho.server.http.HttpRequest.handleRequest(HttpRequest.java:838)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.dispatchRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1309)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequest(TcpSocketLink.java:1265)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequestsImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:1249)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleRequests(TcpSocketLink.java:1157)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketLink.handleAcceptTaskImpl(TcpSocketLink.java:956)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.runThread(ConnectionTask.java:117)
at com.caucho.network.listen.ConnectionTask.run(ConnectionTask.java:93)
at com.caucho.network.listen.SocketLinkThreadLauncher.handleTasks(SocketLinkThreadLauncher.java:169)
at com.caucho.network.listen.TcpSocketAcceptThread.run(TcpSocketAcceptThread.java:61)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.runTasks(ResinThread2.java:173)
at com.caucho.env.thread2.ResinThread2.run(ResinThread2.java:118)
```

Internally we see ORA-25352 “no current transaction” “The user session is not attached to any transaction” during prepare commit phase (call to Oracle JAVA_XA.prepare returns an error code).
It looks as if during inner transaction commit application for some reason involves resources (DataSource) affected in outer transaction which seems to be incorrect because with no db usage in inner transaction we expect no call to Oracle.

The worst thing is that using Apache DBCP pool instead of Resin pool implementation SOLVES the problem… Usage of Atomikos (both TransactionManager implementation and Connections Pool implementation) also works fine. But both mentioned implementations have their own problem.

At the moment we suppose that we are having problem with DB pool or XA driver configuration… 
Could the problem be linked with any enhancements like using local transactions instead of global, etc?
We tried various resources definition (database, resource-ref), used “xa-forbid-same-rm”, switched off spring transaction synchronization, tried to use TransactionManager manually to suspend/resume transaction, etc - everything with no luck.

Any ideas/solutions are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combination Resin/Spring/Oracle/XA Transactions works perfectly.
The key thing here is to work correctly with DB connections.

All DB connections must be opened INSIDE your transaction. In this case this resource will be enlisted for the transaction implicitly.
Our example code does so.

The problem was that we left db connection OPEN when started NEW transaction. This means that db connection provided by Resin's DB pool (aka UserConnection) hadn't been returned to the pool before beginning new transaction.
For some reason Resin TransactionManager implementation added UNreturned db connection to the list of resources used in the inner transaction implicitly. And commit of inner transaction failed because Oracle knows that db connection has already been used in outer uncommitted yet transaction.

One can safely return db connection to the pool. After execution of inner transaction (where all uncommitted changes are not seen because resin will provide you new db connection inside new transaction) you may ask again for db connection in outer transaction and this db connection will be exactly same as the one before starting inner transaction, so you will see all your uncommitted changes. So from resin's connections pool will be provided connection associated with current UserTransaction.

One more important thing - if you use Spring to get connection from data source (DataSourceUtils) you MUST use DataSourceUtils to release connection before starting inner transactions to let Spring know that connection has been returned. Actually another advantage of Spring is that you can have your own additional TransactionSynchronization logic.
You may also use data source directly (without Spring) and in this case you can call connection.close() to return it to the connections pool.

Finally the code of outer transaction (any transaction) should look like:

```
public void doOuterTransaction() throws Throwable {
    DefaultTransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    def.setName("myTx");
    def.setPropagationBehavior(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES);
    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    Connection connection = null;
    Cache cache = null;
    try {
        try {
            cache = ...; // get cache from CacheManager
            connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(myDataSource);
            // some business logic
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, myDataSource);
        }

        doInnerTransaction();

        try {
            cache = ...; // get cache from CacheManager
            connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(myDataSource);
            // some other business logic 
        } finally {
            DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(connection, myDataSource);
        }
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        txManager.rollback(status);
        throw ex;
    }

    txManager.commit(status);
}
```

So do not be afraid of getting and releasing of db connection. You have connections pool - it is fast. Calling close() on connection only returns it to the pool (method name "release" is much better!). Having active UserTransaction will NOT commit your changes until you call commit() explicitly.

Thanks everybody for your help!